# Font is not displaying correctly, using @font-face

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

I am trying to use a font for a website. The typeface file is being loaded in correctly (I can see the file in my network tab), however it is not displaying correctly. I have used font-face to import the fonts, with the following styling rules below,

```
@font-face{
    font-family: 'BwGradual-Thin';
    src:    url('../fonts/BwGradual-Thin.otf') format('opentype'),
            url('../fonts/BwGradual-Thin.woff'),
            url('../fonts/BwGradual-Thin.eot'); 
}

@font-face{
    font-family: 'BwGradual-Regular';
    src:    url('../fonts/BwGradual-Regular.otf') format('opentype'),
            url('../fonts/BwGradual-Regular.woff'),
            url('../fonts/BwGradual-Regular.eot');
  }
```

I have attached 2 screenshots below, the first of the network tab of with the correctly loaded typeface file, which shows how all characters should be displayed on with the font. The second screen shot is how the font displays on the website. Only the 't' character has is displaying correctly.

[Dev Tools Network Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gghUK.png)

[Heading Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCwis.png)

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I see no problem and it seems like it has been applied correctly?  I'm assuming that the word ```art``` is inside a ```<strong>``` tag making it bold ?

Comment: @JuliusGuevarra If you look at the 'r' character and the 'W' character they do not match up with the characters in the font file.

Comment: Have you tried to use the installed font in Photoshop to see their difference? Or try to apply font-smoothing in css ```-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;```

Comment: @JuliusGuevarra Thanks for your persistence. I have a sketch file that the teams graphic designer has supplied to me, where characters appear as defined by the .otf  file. I have tried all the -webkit-font-smoothing options, however no success at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am still unsure as to why the method above does not work, however I have got the font to display correctly. My solutions was;

- Replace .otf files with .ttf (Converted using CloudConvert)
- In font face, declare all fonts as the same family, .i.e. font-family: 'BwGradual' and then declare the font weight of each type. i.e. 100,200,400,etc
- Set -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased. (This was not workign with .otf file types.)

---

Very specific question so, not sure if useful for later uses, but hope it helps.